# jQuery animate toggles away button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I am finding my button sliding away even though I am trying to set it up to be a toggle click for animate. I basically want the button to slide out and in the content links without disappearing the button. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#slidebottom button').toggle(function() {
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-1").animate({left: '-=50', top: '-=50'}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-2").animate({left: '=0', top: '-=50'}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-3").animate({left: '+=50', top: '-=50'}, 500);
            }, function() {
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-1").animate({left: '+=50', top: '+=50'}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-2").animate({left: '=0', top: '+=50'}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-3").animate({left: '-=50', top: '+=50'}, 500);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slidebottom">
   <button>Slide it</button>
   <div id="outer-nav">
     <div class="navlink-1">Link 1</div>
     <div class="navlink-2">Link 2</div>
     <div class="navlink-3">Link 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used when you want to show/hide elements. Since you want for the elements in `#outer-nav` to animate instead of the toggle button, you need to change your code into something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isToggled = false;

    $('#slidebottom button').click(function() {
        if (!isToggled) {
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-1").animate({left: -50, top: -50}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-2").animate({left: 0, top: -50}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-3").animate({left: 50, top: -50}, 500);
        } else {
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-1").animate({left: 50, top: 50}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-2").animate({left: 0, top: 50}, 500);
            $("#outer-nav .navlink-3").animate({left: -50, top: 50}, 500);
        }

        isToggled = !isToggled; 
    });
});
```